# Selenium By.CSS_SELECTOR selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I'm following a tutorial, which is outdated and I'm aware Selenium is undergoing some changes.

However, I have spent multiple hours to get a one-liner to work and just can't figure out what's wrong. Multiple problems that make finding a solution difficult:

1. The documentation mentions find_element and find_elements, but not enough variations in the examples are available.
2. A lot of examples are outdated and show deprecated syntax. Therefore a search on google or stackoverflow yields so many different questions and solutions that filtering out the right one becomes quiet challenging.

And yet here I'm contributing to this issue :-/  Sorry future readers!

Here is what I'm trying:
url = https://www.python.org/
from the "Upcoming events" section, I'm trying to extract a list of dates, event description and link.

Here some info:
#content > div > section > div.list-widgets.row > div.medium-widget.event-widget.last > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > time

#content > div > section > div.list-widgets.row > div.medium-widget.event-widget.last > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a

```
<div class="list-widgets row">

                    <div class="medium-widget blog-widget">
                        
                        <div class="shrubbery">
                        
                            <h2 class="widget-title"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-news"></span>Latest News</h2>
                            <p class="give-me-more"><a href="https://blog.python.org" title="More News">More</a></p>
                            
                            <ul class="menu">
                                
                                
                                <li>
<time datetime="2022-12-22T16:08:00.000003+00:00"><span class="say-no-more">2022-</span>12-22</time>
 <a href="https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2022/12/more-python-everywhere-all-at-once.html">More Python Everywhere, All at Once: Looking Forward to 2023</a></li>
                                
                                <li>
<time datetime="2022-12-22T15:13:34.000003+00:00"><span class="say-no-more">2022-</span>12-22</time>
 <a href="https://mailchi.mp/python/psf-nov-15542733">Python Software Foundation - December 2022 Newsletter</a></li>
                                
                                <li>
<time datetime="2022-12-08T19:16:00.000003+00:00"><span class="say-no-more">2022-</span>12-08</time>
 <a href="https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2022/12/introducing-new-sliding-scale-membership.html">Introducing a New Sliding Scale Membership</a></li>
                                
                                <li>
<time datetime="2022-12-06T22:58:00.000001+00:00"><span class="say-no-more">2022-</span>12-06</time>
 <a href="https://pythoninsider.blogspot.com/2022/12/python-3111-3109-3916-3816-3716-and.html">Python 3.11.1, 3.10.9, 3.9.16, 3.8.16, 3.7.16, and 3.12.0 alpha 3 are now available</a></li>
                                
                                <li>
<time datetime="2022-11-23T23:47:00.000002+00:00"><span class="say-no-more">2022-</span>11-23</time>
 <a href="https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2022/11/where-is-psf.html">Where is the PSF?</a></li>
                                
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- end .shrubbery -->

                    </div>

                    <div class="medium-widget event-widget last">
                        
                        <div class="shrubbery">
                        
                            <h2 class="widget-title"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-calendar"></span>Upcoming Events</h2>
                            <p class="give-me-more"><a href="/events/calendars/" title="More Events">More</a></p>
                            
                            <ul class="menu">
                                
                                
                                
                                <li>
<time datetime="2023-01-18T17:00:00+00:00"><span class="say-no-more">2023-</span>01-18</time>
 <a href="/events/python-user-group/1322/">Python Meeting Düsseldorf</a></li>
                                
                                
                                
                                <li>
<time datetime="2023-02-16T00:00:00+00:00"><span class="say-no-more">2023-</span>02-16</time>
 <a href="/events/python-events/1392/">PyConFr 2023</a></li>
                                
                                
                                
                                <li>
<time datetime="2023-02-21T00:00:00+00:00"><span class="say-no-more">2023-</span>02-21</time>
 <a href="/events/python-events/1379/">PyCon Namibia 2023</a></li>
                                
                                
                                
                                <li>
<time datetime="2023-02-25T00:00:00+00:00"><span class="say-no-more">2023-</span>02-25</time>
 <a href="/events/python-events/1397/">PyCon PH 2023</a></li>
                                
                                
                                
                                <li>
<time datetime="2023-03-06T00:00:00+00:00"><span class="say-no-more">2023-</span>03-06</time>
 <a href="/events/python-events/1391/">GeoPython 2023</a></li>
                                
                                
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved using
a) find_elementa(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
b) find_elementa(By.XPATH,

?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**library/modules** keep on improving so it's a good idea to refer to the official documentation too! Following is an example, which might help you to move forward. 
Note: comments with the code. added import where it's needed, eventually all will be moved on top.

```
#Sources
#https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#
#https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/
#https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/   
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
base_url="https://www.python.org/"
browser.get(base_url)

# Events can be located by either of following , 
events_find_by_xpath= browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@id='events']")
events_find_by_link_text = browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Events')

# Click on Events
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# move to Events and the 1 key down
AC(browser).move_to_element(events_find_by_xpath) \
.key_down(Keys.DOWN) \
.perform()

# once hover, find the link text and click
python_events_find_by_link_text = browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Python Events')
python_events_find_by_link_text.click()


#once on event page get the events, and extract data using beautiful soup as an effective way
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
soup=BS(browser.page_source)

upcoming_events=soup.find("div", {"class": "most-recent-events"})
upcoming_events_all=upcoming_events.find_all("li")
all_events=[]
for each_event in upcoming_events_all:
    each_event_dict={}
    each_event_dict['event-title']=each_event.find("h3",{"class":"event-title"}).text
    each_event_dict['time']=each_event.find("time").text
    each_event_dict['event-location']=each_event.find("span",{"class":"event-location"}).text
    all_events.append(each_event_dict.copy())
    each_event_dict.clear()
```

`all_events` will have the following data, which you can move to csv by `pandas' or so.

```
[{'event-title': 'PyConFr 2023',
  'time': '16 Feb. – 19 Feb.  2023',
  'event-location': 'Bordeaux, France'},
 {'event-title': 'PyCon Namibia 2023',
  'time': '21 Feb. – 23 Feb.  2023',
  'event-location': 'Windhoek, Namibia'},
 {'event-title': 'PyCon PH 2023',
  'time': '25 Feb. – 26 Feb.  2023',
  'event-location': 'Manila, Philippines'},
 {'event-title': 'GeoPython 2023',
  'time': '06 March – 08 March  2023',
  'event-location': 'Basel, Switzerland'},
 {'event-title': 'PyCon DE & PyData Berlin 2023',
  'time': '17 April – 19 April  2023',
  'event-location': 'Berlin, Germany'},
 {'event-title': 'PyCon US 2023',
  'time': '19 April – 27 April  2023',
  'event-location': 'Salt Lake City, Utah, USA'},
 {'event-title': 'XtremePython 2022',
  'time': '27 Dec. 2022',
  'event-location': 'Online'},
 {'event-title': 'PyCon Bolivia 2022',
  'time': '09 Dec. – 10 Dec.  2022',
  'event-location': 'Cochabamba, Bolivia'}]
```

move data to pandas as df

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(all_events)
df
```

Jupiter notebook:[image]